# Nougat - Remove Google Account

Tags: google-account, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s7

My Galaxy S7 recently updated to Android 7.0.

I've got two Google accounts on my phone, personal and work.

I recently left my job and my work Google account has had its password reset.

Since then I'm getting the "Account Action Required" notification to sign back into the account.

This isn't possible as the account will be deleted soon.

For the life of me I can't find where to remove the account from my phone.

This used to be very straightforward. There's a strong possibility that I'm being blind. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. I tried those instructions before but there is no Personal option. I did find it though. For anyone interested, it's Settings > Cloud and Accounts > Accounts > Google > Tap Account > [Menu] > Remove Account. For some reason it wouldn't open up the option to remove the account without having to "cancel sync" first in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be simple. Select Settings -> (Personal) Accounts -> Google -> [Account to remove]

Then select the menu (hamburger) and select "Remove account".

The trouble is that the menus sometimes vary with each manufacturer's OS customizations.